# Overriding Inherited mappings in OnModelCreating

Tags: asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I've a derived context from a base class that implements dbcontext. The **base** class OnModelCreating is like :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<TUser>(b =>
    {
       b.HasIndex(u => u.NormalizedUserName).HasName("UserNameIndex").IsUnique();
       ...
    }
}
```

The **derived** class OnModelBuilder:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Entity...(add my customization)
}
```

Is it possible to drop the "IsUnique" in the derived context?

Comment: It's not unique constraint (which is created with `HasAlternateKey`) but unique index. Anyway, what do you mean by "drop" - totally remove it, i.e. do not create such index?

Comment: I want to allow duplicate NormalizedUserNames. I'm working with users based on ID (int) and not based on UserNames which can be duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the mappings that create something like `HasKey`, `HasAlternateKey`, `HasIndex` cannot be undone. But you can alter their attributes when possible.

In this particular case, you can make the index non unique by specifying `false` for the optional parameter of `IsUnique` method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    builder.Entity<TUser>(b =>
    {
       b.HasIndex(u => u.NormalizedUserName).IsUnique(false);
       ...
    }
}
```